# React Render loop via map - passing extra parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an API list of records that I render via map. I want to add an `isEditAllowed` flag to each record. How do I pass a value that is not part of the array? It doesn't change per record - it is just true/false for them all.

```
export default function UnitList({units, isEditAllowed}){
    
    return (
        <div>
            {units.map(unit) => (
                 <div key={unit.id}>
                     <UnitEditButton
                         id={unit.id}
                         isEditAllowed={isEditAllowed}
                     </>
                 </div>
...
```

How do I make `isEditAllowed` visible to the child component  inside the iterations via map?

Currently, the `<UnitEditButton>` doesn't see any value for `isEditAllowed`.

Comment: if you console.log isEditAllowed before the return what do you get? Also each unit will have the same value for isEditAllowed since it's not in the unit object

Comment: Before the return, it exists. (True or False). Inside the map, it’s undefined.

Comment: Same value: yes. It’s just a flag I use to determine if an edit button will surface for each.

Comment: it seems that you have a typo somewhere, it should be visible

Comment: If it should work, then I must be clobbering that value somewhere else. Thanks